# Cross-domain post with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, post, greasemonkey

I need to post in the background with Greasemonkey. I tried to create an iframe dynamically and post to it, but it didn't work:

```
function crossDomainPost() {
    // Add the iframe with a unique name
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var uniqueString = "CHANGE_THIS_TO_SOME_UNIQUE_STRING";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.contentWindow.name = uniqueString;

    // construct a form with hidden inputs, targeting the iframe
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.target = uniqueString;
    form.action = "http://INSERT_YOUR_URL_HERE";
    form.method = "POST";

    // repeat for each parameter
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME_HERE";
    input.value = "INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE_HERE";
    form.appendChild(input);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Some people say even if we post, we won't be able take the values. if we can't, just making the user visit the page is enough. it can be in JS, jQuery, AJAX post. Not only the form-iframe trick.

Comment: Try searching cross-domain ajax; this is very, very, *very* common problem.

Comment: i searched and have just searched lots... all codes are about jsonp get, request... there is no post article. do you know a good source?

Comment: Yes, well, that's because you need to use `jsonp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greasemonkey has built-in support for cross-domain posting.  You do not need to use jsonp, nor an iframe.  Use [the GM_xmlhttpRequest function](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest#POST_request).

Rather than trying to build a form and post it, you send form-encoded data directly:

```js
var formData1   = "1 INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE_HERE";
var formData2   = "2 INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE_HERE";
var formData3   = "3 INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE_HERE";
// etc.

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "POST",
    url:        "http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH",
    data:       "formData1=" + encodeURIComponent (formData1)
                + "&" + "formData2=" + encodeURIComponent (formData2)
                + "&" + "formData3=" + encodeURIComponent (formData3)
                // etc.
                ,
    headers:    {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    onload:     function (response) {
        console.log (response.responseText);
    }
} );
```

Comment: that looks correct but i can't take $_POST values in the other page. what is the problem? i am trying on localhost by the way.

Comment: My tests show that `$_POST` is still populated, as expected, by an array of the values sent.  If it's not working for you, you will need to open a new question and give the exact code that fails along with what you get with `print_r (file_get_contents("php://input") );`.

Comment: GM 4.0 changed the function to `GM.xmlhttpRequest`.

Comment: @thomasa88, True but  GM4 is a separate tag here, and not applied to this question.  Should use Tampermonkey anyway (no code changes needed), per the recommendation of GM's own developers, since GM4 broke so much and is not backwards compatible.